# Django with Postgres: How To Allow Null as Default in Django Model

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis

I am using Django with Postgres, and trying to load data from csv to table. However, since one filed is Geometry Field, so I have to leave it blank when I load the table(otherwise `\copy from` will fail).

Here's my model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4, default=Decimal('0.0000'))
lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=4, default=Decimal('0.0000'))
geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

and after migration, I ran psql like this:

```
mydb=>\copy target(name,lat,lon) from 'file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;
```

and I get error like this:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "geom" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (name1, 30.4704, -97.8038, null).
CONTEXT:  COPY target, line 2: "name1, 30.4704, -97.8038"
```

and here's the portion of csv file:

```
name,lat,lon
name1,30.4704,-97.8038
name2,30.3883,-97.7386
```

and here's the \d+ target:

```
mydb=> \d+ target
                            Table "public.target"
   Column   |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 name       | character varying(200) | not null  | extended |              | 
 lat        | numeric(6,4)           | not null  | main     |              | 
 lon        | numeric(7,4)           | not null  | main     |              | 
 geom       | geometry(Point,4326)   |           | main     |              | 
Indexes:
    "target_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (name)
    "target_geom_id" gist (geom)
```

So I guess geom is set to null when loading csv to the table? How can I fix it? I want to set the default of filed geom is null so that I can update it use other query.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Looks like I may need something like this in my table `  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'POINT'::text OR geom IS NULL)` then how can I add this to my table through Django? Thanks!

Comment: Constraints are not needed with typmods from PostGIS 2.x that look like `geometry(Point,4326)`. Why would there be an error "null value in column "geom" violates not-null constraint" when there is no such constraint in place? This is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Couple different options, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085785/geodjango-mysql-points-cant-be-null-what-other-empty-value-should-i-use).

You can either:

1) Use a placeholder (0,0) which you can then overwrite.

or:

2) Set `spacial_index=False`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working after tried `spacial_index=False`. The problem for placeholder is that if I know how to present (0,0) in csv so that `\copy` in psql would work, then I don't need to go through all the troubles.. So is it possible what exactly what I should put in csv for the geom field? I tried `ST_GeomFromText(Point(0 0), 4326)` but it failed.