# geometry column contains null values

Tags: python, django, geodjango

So I am trying to add a point field to a model in django which looks like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    geometry = models.PointField(srid=4326,default='POINT(0.0,0.0)')
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I already have database with lots of locations with the lat lng coordinates but they don't need a point field. I am getting this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "geometry" contains null values`

I set the default but it still gives me that error when I run 'python manage.py migrate' How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The `default` does not change old rows in the database (that existed before the migration).  You should set the the `geometry` field to be nullable and then migrate.  Once migrated you can either fill in the null values with the default and remove `null=True` or leave as is</strike>

**UPDATE**

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085785/geodjango-mysql-points-cant-be-null-what-other-empty-value-should-i-use) it seems very possible that `PointField` cannot be `null` (even if it's specified to be which really grinds my gears...).  GIVEN that your model does not need to change but it doesn't look like django can handle this super well for you.

I see two options (better ones might exist)

1. Do the data migration on the actual table yourself (I THINK with most databases when you add in a new column you can set a default there and it will populate that for you)
2. Create a new model which is essentially the same with the new columns, copy the data over, delete the old model and columns.

Neither of these seem ideal but the googles have not yet shown me a better way

Comment: I changed table to ' geometry = models.PointField(srid=4326,null=True)' the makemigations worked but 'python manage.py migrate' throws the same error

Comment: @TylerRice did some more googling and updated my answer, doubt it's perfect but it might help you get going in the right direction